# What is the next item in this numerical sequence?

Tags: mathematics, sequence, letter-sequence

I found this on [a test](http://numericore.weebly.com/numericore-test.html), and it's under "Numerical sequences". I can't figure it out. I tried using the numbers of the alphabet: 1, 2, 9, 12, 1, 2.

A, B, I, L, A, B,?

It doesn't go by the pattern ABIL ABIL ABIL...

Comment: There has been some debate as to whether this question meets our attribution requirements. I've added a link to the exact test that this question is apparently from, which should put that debate to rest.

Comment: @F1Krazy I don't really care about the feelings of the online IQ test creators. I've had terrible experiences with a lot of them. I just wanted to know the answer to the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is

> $Y$

Reason:

> Assume that each element has an index (position) $i$. Now, the element at $i$ is $i^{i-1}\text{ mod }26$. For example,$\text{}\\\\$
> $1^0 \equiv 1 \text{ (mod 26}) = A,\\ 2^1 \equiv 2 \text{ (mod 26}) = B,\\ 3^2 \equiv 9 \text{ (mod 26}) = I,\\ 4^3 = 64 \equiv 12 \text{ (mod 26}) = L,\\ 5^4 = 625 \equiv 1 \text{ (mod 26}) = A,\\ 6^5 = 7776 \equiv 2 \text{ (mod 26})= B,\\ 7^6 = 117649 \equiv 25 \text{ (mod 26}) = Y$

To be exact, it is actually $(x-1) \text{ mod }26+1$ because there will be a conflict for $Z$

Comment: That's clever. How did you come up with that?

Comment: PutnamLegend, he saw 1,2,9, he recognized n^(n-1) series. The alphabet is just like setting a modulus. This, he also recognized. And then it was just done.

Comment: Please try using "mod" instead of "%". The "%" symbol may not be friendly to non-programmers.